# Object[] to double[] c#

Tags: c#, object, double

I have an array of objects[] but I want to convert them to an array of doubles[]
I have the object array dinamicaly as the size is a parameter...

How to do this?

I was doing something like:

```
var doub = (double[])obj;
```

Comment: Probably the best way is not to end up with `object[]` to start with. Consider if you can actually get properly typed array (or even better `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` from whatever returns object[].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another easy way without Linq:

```
var doubles = Array.ConvertAll<object, double>(objects, o => (double)o);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `.Cast<T>()` extension method in the `System.Linq` namespace.

```
var doub = obj.Cast<double>();
```

Comment: @cMinor, yes, lots.  But this is probably the best way.  What sort of different solution are you looking for?

Comment: @cMinor -- but why do you want a solution that avoids Linq?  Very old version of the framework?

Comment: @cMinor Is there a reason Linq can't be used? There's even LinqBridge if you're using .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
object[] o;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
     o[i]=i;
}
double[] d = (double[])o;//Now getting double array.
```